# How can I identify permanently certain builds of my app?

Tags: android

I need to identify certain builds of my app permanently. The reason is, that these will be pre-installed in certain devices and they need some different tracking parameters.

I don't want to create a new app for this - the app has to be the same as the "normal" one, which can be downloaded from Google Play.

Before any app update, the solution is clear - just create 2 different builds, with same package name and signature, one goes directly to be preinstalled on the devices and other to Google Play.

But the preinstalled apps have to receive updates, and AFAIK, all differences will be overwritten.

Possible solutions which come to my mind:

- Pre-installed build saves a preference. Problem: the user can clear the preferences at any moment. This has to be reliable.
- Server side identification. Problem: the app doesn't require user login to be used - so there would be only left the IMEI, which has to be sent to the server the first time to say "I'm preinstalled", but this would need server changes, which are unwanted + not sure about legal implications of sending IMEI (maybe a hash - but still, this isn't nice).
- Identify the app through the place it's stored. But I don't know where people will store these pre installed apps. I assume they go in the same place as normal apps. They are not system apps / firmware. So I guess this is also not a possibility.

Is there any other way to identify my installation subset. Maybe I'm missing something very basic. Or what do you advice, generally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ummm... since you presumably know what device models are the ones getting the pre-install, isn't this a matter of simply adding device model data to your "tracking parameters"?

Comment: I don't know yet about the target group of these pre-installs, it's a good question actually. But I guess that it's not bound to device models + there will be probably people with these device models, which don't have the pre-installs and download the app manually. This method would identify them as pre-install, which is wrong.

Comment: What is the difference between the pre-installed app and the google play one? Ads?

Comment: Well, the marketing team wants to track them separately- they have to be differentiable, for business.

Comment: A factory reset shouldn't affect a pre-installed app, since it will bring its preference back to its original state. What else are you worried about, that the user will actually go into the deeply nested Settings menu, and clear the preference for your exact application? Why? How many people do you think are going to do that to make it statistically significant?

Comment: Yes, I'm worried about the users clearing the app's data in the settings. I'm not very aware of user behavior. Is this rare? I mean really rare?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are doing it wrong. If there are differences, it'd be simpler to do two separate builds, otherwise you will face problems with things being overwritten by updates. Alternatively, you may split your app into modules and only these things that differ should be made different APKs - that way you can still push one update for all your users and keep differences intact

Comment: I would also do 2 separate builds at the beginning. But for the updates, I would need 2 separate *apps* right? 2 different package names. Or how can I update the pre-installed apps?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this - "you may split your app into modules and only these things that differ should be made different APKs - that way you can still push one update for all your users and keep differences intact" Can I push an update with different APKs? (without different apps).

Comment: Concerning the different *apps* topic, besides this is "difficult" I guess it's also incorrect, because the app for the pre-installed users would be also available in Google Play, so "normal" users could also download them... unless I can setup this app to be available "only for updates" or deselect all countries but I guess this will not work.